# Generate Uniformly Random Points on a Transformed Sphere

Tags: geometry, sampling, spheres

I have a sphere transformed by an affine transformation (represented as a 4x4 matrix).  **How should I get uniformly distributed points on the transformed sphere's surface?**

Note that the obvious thing--generating points on an untransformed sphere and then transforming them does not necessarily produce uniformly distributed points.